# How to create grid in yii with custom array?

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I have created an array in php.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ip_addr] => 152.12.40.205
                [Management_col-2] => Success
                [Management_col-3] => Success
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ip_addr] => 152.12.40.206
            [Management_col-2] => Success
            [Management_col-3] => Error
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ip_addr] => 152.12.40.207
            [Management_col-2] => NA
            [Management_col-3] => Success
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ip_addr] => 152.12.40.209
            [Management_col-2] => Success
            [Management_col-3] => Success
        )
);
```

I will have dynamic columns like ip_addr, Management_col-2, ....and so on with there respective dynamic values.

I want to use it in Grid view of YII.

```
    $nc3DataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($alldata);


    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'nc3-audit-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $nc3DataProvider,

));
```

I also want to use filter on the table.

Plz help me for this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is this Yii or Yii2?

Comment: Need this in yii only

Comment: I see. I can't be sure about it then. I know only in Yii2.

Comment: Can't we try same procedure in yii.

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Can you plz give answer for yii2, I will try to make it in yii

Comment: Oh, yea... Sorry for no reponse, I'm trying to finish other things first. But my answer might not be 100% accurate.

Comment: Not an issue, You can try...I tired by trying it. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117522/discussion-between-amol-and-edvin-tenovim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CArrayDataProvider this a sample

Controller

```
public function actionGridViewArray() {
 $rawData=array(
         array('id'=>1, 'username'=>'from', 'email'=>'array'),
         array('id'=>2, 'username'=>'test 2', 'email'=>'hello@example.com'),
     );

     // or using: $rawData=User::model()->findAll();
     $arrayDataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
         'id'=>'id',
         /* 'sort'=>array(
             'attributes'=>array(
                 'username', 'email',
             ),
         ), */
         'pagination'=>array(
             'pageSize'=>10,
         ),
     ));
     $params =array(
         'arrayDataProvider'=>$arrayDataProvider,
     );
     if(!isset($_GET['ajax'])) $this->render('grid_view_array', $params);
     else  $this->renderPartial('grid_view_array', $params);
 }
```

View  (gridview)

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data["username"])'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => 'raw',
           'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data["email"]), "mailto:".CHtml::encode($data["email"]))',
        ),
    ),
));
```

And buildin the column dinamically

```
foreach ($header as $cols){ 
   $column[] = array( 'name'=> $cols, 
   'value'=>'isset($data[\''.$cols.'\'])?$data[\''.$cols.'\']:""', ); 
}


$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $arrayDataProvider,
    'columns' => $column
));
```

Comment: I have dynamic columns in grid, it can be change, its name and number columns too with its value. So how can i implement it? Here u have taken only username and email in columns array.

Comment: this seems another answer ..  anyway you can set the dataProvider based in your dinamic array and also you can use a var for the column and you can build the var with the columns coniguration as you need ..  but this i repeart seems another question to me ..

Comment: `foreach ($header as $cols){
    $column[] =  
        array(
            'name'=> $cols,
            'value'=>'isset($data[\''.$cols.'\'])?$data[\''.$cols.'\']:""',
        
    );
}`


I have used this to set columns in grid: 
'columns' => $column,

Its makes my work done..
Thanxs for ur support @scaisEdge

Comment: I have update the answer with   a suggestion based on your comment

Comment: Well then is that you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want.